# Let $N(t)$ is a poisson process with rate $\lambda$, $T^* \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda^*)$, find the expectation of $N(\min(t, T^*))$

Tags: self-study, survival, expected-value, poisson-process

Currently, my approach is to split $N(\min(t, T^*))$ like the following by [the law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation).

\begin{align*}
&E(N(\min(t,T^*))) = E(N(t \wedge T^*)) \\
    = {}&E(N(t\wedge T^*) \mid t \le T^*) \cdot P(t \le T^*) + E(N(t\wedge T^*) \mid t > T^*) \cdot P(t > T^*). 
\end{align*}

To make it less confusing and more concrete, one could think of the target expectation as $E(N(\min(3, T^*)))$ when $t=3$. Later, generalize the solution to suit any given $t$.

The first and second parts become

\begin{align*}
&E(N(t\wedge T^*)\mid t \le T^* )\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x P(N(t\wedge T^*) = x\mid t \le T^*)\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x \frac{P(N(t\wedge T^*) = x, t \le T^*)}{P(t \le T^*)}\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x \frac{P(N(t) = x, t \le T^*)}{P(t \le T^*)}\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x \frac{P(N(t) = x) P(t \le T^*)}{P(t \le T^*)}\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x P(N(t) = x)\\
={}& E(N(t)) = \lambda t;
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
&E(N(t\wedge T^*) \mid t > T^*)\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x P(N(t\wedge T^*) = x\mid t > T^*) \hspace{1cm}\color{red}{T^* < t}\\ 
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x \frac{P(N(t\wedge T^*) = x \mid t > T^*)}{P(t > T^*)} \\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x \frac{P(N(t\wedge T^*) = x ,t > T^*)}{P(t > T^*)}\\
={}& \sum_{x = 0}^\infty x \frac{P(N(T^*) = x ,T^* < t)}{P(T^* < t)}
\end{align*}

by the [conditional expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation).

So, the problem is $N(T^*)$ and $T^*$  are less likely to be independent; how to find the probability $P(N(T^*) = x ,T^* < t)$?

Comment: Please consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag.

Comment: I think you're doing a little more work than you need to; you can work directly with the expectations, instead of having to go back to the summations.  For example, if $T^*>t$, then $\mathbb{E}N(\cdot) =\mathbb{E}N(t)= \lambda t$, and we don't need to write stuff out.  Similarly, $\mathbb{E}N(T^*)$ is *linear* in $T^*$, which makes calculations for the $T^* < t$ case straightforward.

Comment: @jbowman. Thanks for your comments. And yes, the first term essentially ends up with $\lambda t$. I did a simulation, which is consistent with $\lambda t$. Do you mean the second term would look like $\lambda T^*$, since $T^*$ is a variable ($0 < T^* < t$), then do the integration over it? That is an interesting approach; I will try that and let you know.

Comment: Yes; it's an application of the law of total expectation again.

Comment: @jbowman, I just tried the simulation as suggested. Unfortunately, the second term still has some underestimation at the beginning of $t$, then converges at the end. I believe the problem is still $E(N(T^*))$ is *linear* relying on $N(T^*)$ and $T^*$ are independent, which is less likely.

Comment: I am unable to decipher the notation.  Evidently $N(T)$ is a Poisson variable, so presumably it is the count of events during any interval of measure $T.$ However, it also looks like you are *conditioning* on $T,$ implying $T$ is a random variable -- but what kind of object is it really?  And if it's a random variable, what is its distribution?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for your comments. $N(t)$ is a Poisson variable, it is also equivalent to $N(T=t)$, $t$ is a realization of $T$. For any $t > 0$, $N(t)$ is a Poisson variable. Conventionally, it is denoted as {N(t), t>0}, aka, Poisson point process. In my particular problem setting, $Y = \min(T, T^*)$, I put it as $T$ is to indicate the fact $T$ could be any time point. To make it less confusing, I just edited the question accordingly.

Comment: That helps, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the law of total expectations to simplify the problem as follows:

$$\mathbb{E} N(\min(t,T^*)) = \lambda \mathbb{E}\min(t,T^*)$$

Finding $\mathbb{E} \min(t,T^*)$ is straightforward:

$$\mathbb{E} \min(t,T^*) = \mathbb{E} (T^*|T^*\leq t)P(T^*\leq t) + tP(T^*> t) \tag 1$$

Using the memoryless property of the exponential distribution allows us to simplify further, as:

$$\mathbb{E} T^* = \mathbb{E}(T^*|T^*\leq t)P(T^*\leq t) + \mathbb{E}(T^*|T^*> t)P(T^*> t)$$

and $\mathbb{E} (T^*|T^*> t) = \lambda^*+t$ while $\mathbb{E} T^* = \lambda^*$.  Therefore, rearranging terms,

$$\mathbb{E}(T^*|T^*\leq t)P(T^*\leq t) = \lambda^* - (\lambda^*+t)P(T^*>t)$$

Substituting into the right hand side of eq. (1) gives us:

$$\mathbb{E}\min(t,T^*) = \lambda^* - (\lambda^*+t)P(T^*>t) + tP(T^*> t) = \lambda^*(1-e^{-t/\lambda^* })$$

One more substitution gets us to:

$$\mathbb{E} N (\min(t,T^*)) = \lambda \lambda^*(1-e^{-t/\lambda^* })$$

Now for a check via simulation.  We will set $\lambda = 1.138$, $\lambda^* = 0.842$, and $t = 1.234$:

```
lambda <- 1.138
lambdastar <- 0.842
tc <- 1.234
 
tstar <- rexp(100000, 1/lambdastar)
x <- rpois(100000, lambda*pmin(tstar, tc))
 
lambda*lambdastar*(1-exp(-tc/lambdastar))
[1] 0.7369016
 
mean(x)
[1] 0.73378
sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
[1] 0.003133204
```

which seems to match as well as we would hope.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, I am running an simulation on a continuous scale of $X$ and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I mean the continuous scale of $tc$ in your simulation. The result is consistent for any $tc$. Thanks so much for your generous help.